# Why does Munkres write that $f$ is bijective and continuous?

Tags: general-topology

I have some doubts abot Munkres's topology

[image]

My doubts: here  $f([0,\frac{1}{4}))$ is not open in $S^1$ because $f([0,1/4))$ lying in the first quadrant. we know that continuous image of open set is open.

Now my question: Why does Munkres write that $f$ is bijective and continuous?

Comment: The image of an open set under a continuous map needn't be open.  For example, every constant map is continuous, but the image of a constant map is a singleton point which, with respect to the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ (for example) is not open.  A function is continuous if the **preimage** of an open set is open.

Comment: In general, a continuous image of an open set need not be open. It is the inverse image of an open set that is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, $f([0, \frac{1}{4})$ is not open in $S^1$. That doesn't mean $f$ isn't continuous though; it is the preimages of open sets that make functions continuous, not the images.

Comment: ..@ Duncan what about bijective    why Munkres wriiten $f$  is bijective ?

Comment: @jasmine Because $f$ is bijective.

Comment: Got its @Duncan..thanks u

Answer (score -1):

The function $f:\mathbb{[0,1)}\to S^1$ defined by $f(t)=\bigl(\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t)\bigr)$ is continuous and bijective

But $f$ cannot be a homeomorphism, because $U=S^1\setminus\{{p}\}$ is connected,   but $f^{-1}(U)=[0,1)\setminus\{p\}$ is not connected.

Comment: That function isn't bijective. You have defined the domain as $\mathbb{R}$, but $f(1) = f(0)$, so it isn't injective. This is why Munkres restricts the domain to $[0, 1)$.

Comment: yes i edits its now   @DuncanRamage thanks u

Comment: A pedantic correction about your proof: $[0, 1) - \{p\}$ may actually be connected, if $p = 0$. However, the proof is still fundamentally sound, as $S^1$ is connected by removing *any* one point, while $[0, 1)$ only has one such point.